# combining and looping through lists python

Tags: python

```
first_name = ["Johnny", "Joseph", "Mary"]
third_name = ["Mendez", "Nash", "Johanson"]
second_name = ["John", "Allen", "Ann"]


for i in first_name:
    for x in second_name:
        for y in third_name:
            names = i + x + y
```

how can we make the output:

```
[Johnny John Mendez, Joseph Allen Nash, Mary Ann Johanson]
```

because the when I loop through all the lists I get jumbled names. How can we make the order of the names. `first_name second_name third_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
map(" ".join, zip(first_names, second_names, third_names))
```

Example in the REPL:

```
>>> map(" ".join, zip(["A", "B", "C"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]))
['A a 1', 'B b 2', 'C c 3']
```

and then you can create a function you might use elsewhere:

```
def make_names(first_names, second_names, third_names):
    return map(" ".join, zip(first_names, second_names, third_names))
```

or even more general not hardcoding exactly three name parts:

```
def make_names(*args):
    return map(" ".join, zip(*args))
```

REPL example:

```
>>> make_names(["a"])
['a']
>>> make_names(["a"], ["b"])
['a b']
>>> make_names(["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"])
['a b c d']
>>> make_names(["Johnny", "Joseph", "Mary"], ["Mendez", "Nash", "Johanson"], ["John", "Allen", "Ann"])
['Johnny Mendez John', 'Joseph Nash Allen', 'Mary Johanson Ann']
```

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) takes a function and an iterable as arguments, and calls the function for every element in the iterable, returning a list of the results. Here's a simple [example](http://pastebin.com/jjZwEPrJ).

Comment: hey i looked at your code and it produces this "<map object at 0x040302F0>" why?

Comment: Hey @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez this is presumably a generator for the "list". It's a performance optimisation that Python can pull off. You can still iterate the thing and it behaves exactly like a list. Try `list(map(" ".join, zip(["A", "B", "C"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"])))` or `list(whatever)` to actually create a list object.
These generators can be beneficial if you for example have something like a "infinite list", then with a generator you don't need to store the whole list in memory (which would be impossible for an infinite one). But you can still always give the next element.

Comment: what Python version do you have actually and what exactly is the expression you evaluate? In any case it doesn't matter for the result really but Python might be helping you by creating something more performant. It should also be better performance-wise than the versions with the `for` loops, however I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for first, second, third in zip(first_name, second_name, third_name):
    print "{} {} {}".format(first, second, third)
```

The `zip` function iterates through the three lists at the same time, and takes the corresponding element from each list on each iteration.

Comment: so that means i dont use a for loop? wow i didn't know about zip thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you have lists of unequal size

```
In [18]: import itertools
In [19]: [x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip_longest(first_name,second_name,third_name)) if x]
Out[19]:["Johnny","John Mendez","Joseph", "Allen", "Nash", "Mary", "Ann", "Johanson"]
```